# Accidentally disabled RDP access on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I was trying to revert some firewall rules. I clicked "Reset everything back to default" on Windows Firewall and now I can't connect to my server via Windows Remote Desktop application. I think it took it literally and went all back to stonehenge. It's absolutely my fault that I didn't know such a thing would happen. No arguing here.

I tried to login via rescue mode but it doesn't react at all. I have KVM access (it says "KVM OVER IP" on my server console), but I don't know if it helps or not.

What I can do now, besides installing it again? I have my backups but I rather not to do a fresh install.

This is a server that I rent from a dedicated server provider called online.net, so I don't have physical access to the server.

Comment: We kinda need more specifics, is this a native Windows Server 2012 install or a virtual machine? If native, don't you have physical access to the machine?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't provided enough information. This is a dedicated server that I rent from online.net, so I don't have physical access to the server.

Comment: Ok... But if you do a clean install you have to have some kind of access to the server. You know what I mean? If windows isn't running you can't connect to it so there must be some kind of out-of-band management involved you can connect to (e.g. Dell DRAC) if you want to do a clean install. Or do you have to make online.net install it for you?

Comment: I can reinstall it myself using my panel. A few minutes ago I changed its state to rescue mode. It gave me the VNC thing, but I can't connect to it, either.

Comment: But this "VNC thing" is exactly what you need, what do you mean with "you can't connect to it"? How did you try to connect? Usually there's credentials involved since this isn't the direct connection to the server but the connection to the host that hosts the vm of your server and then creates a connection between you and your vm (just like you physically sat in front of it).

Comment: You have KVM OVER IP access to the server. This gives you console access to the server, from which you can fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I have KVM access (it says "KVM OVER IP" on my server console), but I don't know 
>   if it helps or not.

That is all you need, because that does give you "physical access". KVM works on a hardware level and does NOT rely on RDP...

Go to KVM, log into the server, reenable your firewall rules.